# Laravel 8 Rate Limiter cache keys

Tags: laravel, caching, key, unique, limit

We're using Laravel (8) rate limiter and running into constant duplicate key violations in our cache table. Postgres is throwing fits because of the constant attempts to write to the cache with the same key. We're getting duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cache_key_unique" errors, and it looks like every time (and with everyone) it's the same key.

Shouldn't the keys that are generated (I assume automatically by Laravel) be unique already? Or, did we miss something in the configurations?

-DO

Comment: Are you facing exceptions that prevent the project from being functioned or do you simply stumble upon exceptions in the `catch` block of the `Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback()`? If the latest, then this is the designed logic of the upsert query (see `Illuminate\Cache\DatabaseStore::add()`).